# In Hibernate-Envers how to make earlier revison of an entity the latest revision

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

My application uses Hibernate-Envers 4.3.11

- I load music files into my database with their metadata (e.g album title, artist) represented as an audited *Song* class
- Then app edits the metadata in various ways, and writing back to the Song class (each time session committed creates another revision)
- Then usually at the end the changes are written from the current Song class back to the file itself.
- But if running in **Preview Mode** nothing is written to the file. So I want latest version of the Song class for that file to now contain the same metadata as the version that was created when the file was originally loaded.

Currently I do this by getting the first revision of Song and copying the data it holds to the latest version of Song. **but is there a way I can just say take this earlier revision and make it the latest revision**.

**Update**

I am now implementing the answer of Naros. So now I have a class called *SongFile* that always represents the contents of the music file on disk,  this is @Audited (by Envers) and the primary id is a @GeneratedValue.

Then we have a class called *Song*, after an *SongFile* entity is created and omitted we create an equivalent *Song* entity. This is not audited and the primary id is manually set, we set the primaryId and all the metadata so the same as the Song class.

The app then modifies the metadata to *Song*.

Then at conclusion if in *Preview mode*, we just compare differences between *Song* and *SongFile* and generate report.

If in *Real save* mode, we compare differences between *Song* and *SongFile* and generate report and save changes back to file, and *SongFile*.

**This is working great** and solves a number of problems.

However I have an issue, music files can also store multiple images (jpegs etc) we model this with a *CoverImage* class representing the image, and a *CoverArt* class that provides a 1:M link between *Song* and *CoverImage*, also stores a name attribute.

Now the problem is that I created a *CoverArtFile* class used by *SongFile* that uses @GeneratedValue and a *CoverArt* class  used by *Song* that doesn't autogen.

When originally loading a file and creating *SongFile* and *Song* this works fine, copying over the autogenned value from any `CoverArtFile` classes to *CoverArt* class

However if we have no coverart to start with and then it is added by the app we fail because the *CoverArt* class doesn't autogen primary key and I cannot safetly generate one in case it is used by an existing *CoverArtFile* class( or will be in future).

If alternatively I have CoverArt using an autogened value then it wont be the same value as used by its associated CoverArtFile class.

How do I proceed ?

Comment: So in preview mode you allow the transaction to commit to the database even though those changes are not desired?

Comment: The changes are (possibly) desired but are only written to the database not the file itself so that we can then create a report showing the changes that could have been made to file if not running in preview mode.

Comment: So @Naros any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is no automated way to do what you request.  This process has to be completely manual and coded in the application as there are many entity nuances and business considerations that are best left to the application to decide and handle.

So the best way to do this would be

1. Fetch the desired revision from the audit history that you want to revert to.
2. Fetch the existing entity from Hibernate.
3. Set the values in the existing entity from (2) with those from the desired revision fetched in (1).
4. Merge the modified entity.

Another idea that might work would be to consider separating the concept of *preview* and *non-preview*.  What I mean is you have two entities rather than a single `Song`.  You have one that represents the highly voltile version for *preview* and another for the less voltile *non-preview* that is meant to represent the file contents.

In this approach when you modify the *preview* variant, you're just creating a change log with Envers for things that could have  been made to the file but were not due to *preview-mode*.  When you modify the *non-preview* variant, you're creating a change log for what the file contents **should be**.

The caveat here is your business logic should probably also synchronize the *preview* variant in this use case so that both the *preview* and the *non-preview* have the same contents, so basically load the *preview* entity, modify it to match the *non-preview* and then save the changes for it too.

If both entity types have a common primary key or natural-id, this should be easy enough to manage and allow you to generate all types of reports and maintain consistent history without mixing concerns.

#### UPDATE

To add to my answer regarding your update; this is where you probably will want to use generated identifiers for all entities and have your `Song` and `CoverArt` entities maintain a refererence to either the audited entity or at the very least store the primary key value.

As an example

```
@Entity
public class Song {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  @OneToOne
  private SongFile songFile;      
}
```

or more simply

```
@Entity
public class Song {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private Long songFileId;
}
```

The idea is that your non-file based entities maintain a relationship to the file side either by an association (e.g. `@OneToOne`) or store the identifier of the associated entity so that you can determine if you need to fetch/replicate or construct/insert.

Comment: Okay thanks for confirming it cannot be done automatically. I understand your alternative idea, however the starting point for Preview would be the existing contents of the file (non_preview) therefore after first loading file and creating song I would then have to create preview and copy data over  then at final stage if not preview mode I would have to copy over again. So I am not sure if that is better than what I currently have but I will give it further consideraton.

Comment: Hmm I think it is a good idea but complicated by the fact that song does have some 1:M relationship with some other data (CoverArt) that would also need to be duplicated.

Comment: I am implementing your solution as I see it can solve a number of issues, however I am having a problem with CoverArt. I have updated by question and I hope you can help me with it.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Please see my update and let me know if that addresses your more recent concerns with the approach.

Comment: I have no need to do this for Song class, but okay I was already thinking that I would have to autogen CoverArt Id and this does offer a way to keep track although not quite as simply as with Song class.